# Case when returning null row

Tags: sql, oracle

Below are my tables:

```
T1:
ID 
1
2
3

T2:
ID (fk) value
1        Apple
1        Chocolate
2        Carrot
2        Chocolate
3        Candy
3        Chocolate
```

In my query:

```
select t1.id,
case when (t2.a) like 'app%'
  then 'Apple'
end as 'Fruits',
case when (t2.a) like 'car%'
  then 'Carrot'
end as 'Veggies'
from t1, t2
where t1.id = t2.id
```

here is how my output is:

```
id  Fruits  Veggies
=====================
1   Apple
1
2            Carrot
2
3
```

I see that in the output, I get two rows, one with a match 'fruit'/'veggie' and one with `null`. 
Why is the query returning a null row as well? 
Sorry if my example is not that great. Basically I am trying to create 2 more columns with some text identifiers.

I am expecting an output like:

```
id  Fruits  Veggies
    =====================
 1   Apple
 2            Carrot
 3
```

EDIT:
I have added the table structure above and updated the query with from and where clauses. After implementing the condition in the where clause, I realized the IDs without Apple or Carrot like #3 will not be returned at all if I have the said condition in the where clause.

Comment: Post your whole query; you seem to be missing the from clause;  also, if you could post your table and some sample data it would be helpful.

Comment: Why are you ignoring Kateract's comment? You are being told that you are not showing the part of the query that decides which rows are shown in your result. But instead of adding the FROM and WHERE clause you change your question by suddenly introducing ID 3. Which again has nothing to do with the part of the query you are showing, but once more with the part you are *not* showing.

Comment: looks you have a bad JOIN, the fact that id is twice means that you may be missing a condition on your JOIN.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - I edited the question because after I got a few comments, I thought I did not have the complete information the first time. Also, I think the issue is with the case statement hence I did not post the complete query as it is very long and I feel I got the answer with just the part I posted.

Comment: @Kateract - I am sorry I did not ignore your comment if you felt the same, but my query is really long and I need to redo it to post it here. Also, I thought I did not do the case statement right hence I did not post it.

Comment: @FernandoGutierrez - the ID is a f.key in that table, not PK.

Comment: @Skn The `CASE` statement will not change the number of rows that are returned in your query, but the `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses will.  The most likely cause of extra rows is a bad join, which would come from your `FROM` clause.  I honestly don't know how anyone can provide a credible answer without this information.

Comment: @Kateract - I have added the table structure and the from and where clauses pertaining to these tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting result rows you don't want. Exclude them in your `WHERE` clause:

```
where t1.a like 'app%' or t1.a like 'car%'
```

**UPDATE:** You have updated your question and want to show an ID 3 which is not in your results. Still you don't show your FROM and WHERE clause. If there is a row you want to show, but you are not showing yet, then either your existing WHERE clause is too restrictive or you are using an inner join where you want an outer join.

**UPDATE2:** Now that you have updated your request again showing table structure and content, it shows that you want two query results actually: The apples and carrots (this is a non-aggregating query) plus a record for every ID that has neither the one nor the other (which is an aggregate; you look at all an ID's records to determine whether the condition is true or not). You'd glue these two queries together with `UNION ALL`.

```
select 
  t2.id,
  case when t2.a like 'App%' then 'Apple' end as "Fruits",
  case when t2.a like 'Car%' then 'Carrot' end as "Veggies"
from t2
join t1 on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.a like 'App%' or t2.a like 'Car%'
union all
select id, null, null
from t2
group by id
having max(case when a like 'App%' or a like 'Car%' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Remarks:

- Table t1 is not really needed in this query, but I guess it is in your real query, so I kept it in.
- Your join syntax is out-dated by more than twenty years and should no longer be used. I replaced it with a proper explicit join.
- The single quote is for string literals. Use double quotes for alias names instead.
- Oracle is usually case sensitive. I am surprised `like 'app%'` works for you. It should be `t2.a like 'App%'` or `lower(t2.a) like 'app%'` in my opinion.

Comment: thank you! I think I need to add the condition to my where clause. i did not post the complete query because I was under the impression that the case statement has the issue because I omitted the else.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I originally misinterpreted the question and assumed you were looking to try and replace the null values next to found values in the rows which provided a result.  This is why I suggested including an ELSE.  I changed the example to include the filter in a WHERE clause so you don't get rows which have neither app% or car%.

Example:

```
select t1.id,
case when (t1.a) like 'app%' then 'Apple'
end as 'Fruits'
case when (t1.a) like 'car%' then 'Carrot'
end as 'Veggies'
where t1.a like 'app%' or t1.a like 'car%'
```

Comment: That's what I guessed could be happening! how can this be written in a way that it does not return nulls? I only want the text to be populated if there is a match for 1 ID. if there is no match, it can be null for that row.

Comment: So you want the row to not appear if there is not a match for 'Apple' or 'Carrot' because it would just be an empty row basically.

Comment: I expect only 1 match per ID, so I am expecting only 1 row per ID either with or without a match.

Comment: Oh I get what you're saying somewhat.  So you have multiple rows from the table you're pulling data from with the same t1.id value and one of them is the correct 'Apple' find but since it also contains a row with another item that's neither Apple or Carrot it produces the empty row for you. If I'm interpreting that right.

Comment: You got it..great! sorry if you had to decode my comment.. I was not able to explain it that well :D

Comment: In that case you really don't need to have the else statements in there to provide a filler value for the nulls on the line where you find a result.

Comment: and thats why I did not add the else. but I get the nulls now!

Comment: I may need your help again! I have updated the question!

Answer (score 0):

Given your updated info, you need a left join instead of a inner join.

```
select t1.id,
case when (t2.a) like 'app%' then 'Apple' end as 'Fruits',
case when (t2.a) like 'car%' then 'Carrot' end as 'Veggies'
from t1 left join t2
on t1.id = t2.id
  and (t2.a like 'app%' or t2.a like 'car%')
```

This will allow all 3 id's to show up, but only give you rows where there is an apple or a carrot on the right table, as the where condition is moved to the join.